# CMD problems in reaching dex2jar

Tags: cmd, apk, dex2jar

"dex2jar classes.dex" is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

i got this problem when im trying to generate a classes.dex.jar

i think my environment variables have the problem but i cant figure it out..,

HELP ME OUT!!

THANKS IN ADVANCE

Answer (score 0):

1. provide a snippet of your code (to make answering your question easier). 2. you could try using the start command like this:

   ```
   start your-programs-divided by "|" or "&" then "the path of the file here" (in quotes)
   ```

another quick note you may need to have it open a java in order to run the .JAR file.